# "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" error despite .git directory being present

Tags: git

I have a directory called `lucy` which has a `.git` directory in it:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ ls -a
.           .gitignore      docker-compose.yml
..          Dockerfile      lucy-app
.DS_Store       Procfile        lucy-web
.git            crontab         readme.md
```

However, when I try to do `git status` I get a `Not a git repository` error:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I am almost certain that this command worked in this directory before. The `.git` directory seems to have the relevant contents:

```
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy kurtpeek$ cd .git
Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:.git kurtpeek$ ls
ORIG_HEAD   objects     refs
logs        packed-refs subtree-cache
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing to a random repo of mine, you seem to be missing a `HEAD` file in the `.git` directory. You could try to create it with this line as the content:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Before you touch anything though, I would strongly advise you to create a backup of the entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup and try using `git remote add origin <repository_url>`

if its throws an error, initialize git again

```
git init
```

add your remote again and try, if its ok, paste your backup and commit.